# ASP.NET checkbox values only available after second postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autopostback

I have a problem with the availability of the values of checkboxes and dropdownlists in my webforms page. I think that there is something obvious that I can't see. There is probably a mistake in my idea so I won't post the whole code for now.

What I want to do:
On my page there is a survey (textboxes, checkboxes and dropdowns) and a scroll fixed panel (it stays at the same position in the browser window when scrolling). Depending on the selections made the fixed panel should show information. This information should update everytime a checkbox is un/checked or a dropdown is selected.

What I have done:
The survey is created programmatically on first page_load and added to a panel (=Panel1). There are two languages so I create the every item of the survey twice and store its panel in the browser session (don't know if thats the right way to achieve this but it seems to work). That means I get the whole English survey from "langPanels["EN"].

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (IsPostBack) {
                langPanels = (Dictionary<String,Panel>) HttpContext.Current.Session["panels"];
                Panel1.Controls.Clear();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(langPanels[SelectLanguage.SelectedValue]);

                updateQuestions(); //Survey is evaluated and information is stored in weigthDictionary and blockedResults
                ranking.Text = PrintKeysAndValues(weigthDictionary, blockedResults);
            }
            else {
                createLanguageSelectionList(); //Here the dropdown for the different languages is created
                createLanguagePanels(); //Here all language surveys are created and stored to the current session
            }
        }
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Welcome" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="class._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="SelectLanguage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectLanguage_Change"/><br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"/>

</asp:Content>
```

[EDIT1:]
Creating of the checkboxes (this.panel is afterwards added to langPanels. Method is called whithin createLanguagePanels):
[/EDIT]

```
private void asp_createCheckboxQuestion(String question, String questionID, String[] checkboxes, String[] answerIDs) {

            Label questionLabel = new Label();
            questionLabel.Text = question;
            this.panel.Controls.Add(questionLabel);
            this.panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />")); 

            CheckBoxList checkBoxList = new CheckBoxList();
            checkBoxList.ID = questionID;
            checkBoxList.AutoPostBack = true;
            checkBoxList.CellPadding = 5;
            checkBoxList.CellSpacing = 5;
            checkBoxList.RepeatColumns = 1;
            checkBoxList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;
            checkBoxList.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Table;
            checkBoxList.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;
            checkBoxList.EnableViewState = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < checkboxes.Length; i++) {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = checkboxes[i];
                item.Value = answerIDs[i];
                checkBoxList.Items.Add(item);
            }

            this.panel.Controls.Add(checkBoxList);
            this.panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />")); 

        }
```

Everything works fine except that the information in the fixed panel only is available after I clicked a second checkbox. For example there are 3 checkboxes. The first is clicked and nothing happens in the fixed panel. The second one is clicked and the panel shows information for the first checkbox. The third one is clicked and the panel shows information for first and second checkbox. [EDIT2:] Although their checked states persists through the autoPostBack.[/EDIT]

Comment: `this.panel is afterwards added to Panel1` -  i suspect this is not what happening. How is `asp_createCheckboxQuestion` called?

Comment: Sorry my fault: this.panel is afterwards added to langPanels which is stored in the browser session. The method is called whithin createLanguagePanels().

Comment: Ok, this is still not all. This method does not sign up to the events generated by checkboxes. How are the panels updated in that case? Obviously if the problem is with how checkboxes are added to the panel - code that adds them during post backs is relevant, right?

Comment: @Andrei: I don't have event handlers for the checkboxes, they only have the autoPostBack attribute set to true. But their "right" values are only available after a second postBack. I don't think it is the way the checkboxes are added to the panel, because they work fine (they even have their checked state saved after the autoPostBack)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake:

The problem was that I chose the detour through the browser session. That way the values of the survey were only known after a second postback. I solved it by creating the survey everytime a postback is executed:

```
if (IsPostBack) {
  Panel p = createLanguagePanels();
  Panel1.Controls.Clear();
  Panel1.Controls.Add(p);
}
else {
  createLanguageSelectionList();

  Panel p = createLanguagePanels();
  Panel1.Controls.Clear();
  Panel1.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

I don't know why the selected values are still be selected after postback (they are newly created each time!?), but they do. I know this is an awful solution so if there are better ways of doing this I will appreciate knowing about them!